# Why does the navbar change position when using the dropdown menu?

Tags: css

I've some troubles with the navigation bar from my website. The position of the navigation bar changes when the dropdown menu becomes visible. 
Also when resizing the browser the navigation bar change. 
This is ofcource not really my intention. So please can someone help me?
I would appreciated very much.

This is my css code I'm using.

```
/*main menu*/

.nav-top  {list-style:none;               
}
ul.nav-top ul { margin-top:-40px; margin-bottom:-50px; margin-left:-21px; margin-right:-50;
               position: relative; display:none; }

ul.nav-top li { display:inline-block;
                padding:40px; 
                margin-right:19px;
                position:relative;
}
ul.nav-top li:hover> ul { display:block; }

ul.nav-top li a { display:block;
    text-decoration:none; 
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent; 
}

ul.nav-top a:hover{ color:#686A6A;
                    border-bottom:2px solid #E4E4E4;
 }


/*sub menu*/

ul.nav-top ul ul { clear:both;
border: solid 1px ffffff;  }

ul.nav-top li li {
    display:block;
 /* Introducing a padding between the li and the a give the illusion spaced items */
    padding:2px; padding-top:10px;
    } 
ul.nav-top ul ul li {   
}

ul.nav-top ul ul a{
    white-space:nowrap; /* Stop text wrapping and creating multi-line dropdown items */
    }

ul.nav-top ul ul li:hover a{ /* The persistent hover state does however create a global style for links even before they're hovered. Here we undo these effects. */
    text-decoration:none; background:#FFF; 

}
ul.nav-top ul ul li:hover a:hover{ /* Here we define the most explicit hover states--what happens when you hover each individual link. */
  color:#686A6A; border-bottom:2px solid #E4E4E4;   
}
```

Comment: Hey Jolien! Can you post your HTML too?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've written my HTML code down here.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer. 
This is my HTML:

```
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">

<img src="images/logo-marco-kaller.png">

    <ul class="nav-top">
    <li><a href="home.html">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">work</a>
        <ul>
             <li><a href="#">design</a></li> 
             <li><a href="#">paintings</a></li>   
             <li><a href="#">sculptures</a></li>           
        </ul>    
    <li><a href="shop.html">shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.html">news</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

 <div id="background"></div>


  <div class="wrapper">   

  <div id="content-background"><br>
 <h1>Marco Kaller</h1> 
 <p>Welkom op de site van Marco Kaller!</p>

  <div id="content">
  </div> 
  </div>
</div>

  <div id="footer">   
    <a href="#"><img width="25" height="25" alt="facebook Marco Keller" src="images/facebook.png" /></a>

     <ul class="talen">
     <li>language:</li>
     <li><a href="#">en</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">nl</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">de</a></li>
     </ul>
       <hr class="faded" />
     </div>
```